# Why Ansible is ignoring my 'sudo: False'?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I intend to use ansible to deploy a remote file, since the remote location can only be written with 'root', and local file cannot be downloaded with 'root', I use the following playbook:

```
# in the main playbook

- hosts: master
  user: ec2-user
  sudo: yes
```

```
# in role definition

# download only in the ansible master node
- local_action: get_url url={{ hadoop_mirrors|random }}/hadoop-{{ hadoop_version }}/hadoop-{{ hadoop_version }}.tar.gz dest=/opt/hadoop-{{ hadoop_version }}.tar.gz force=no
  sudo: False
  register: result
  until: result|success
  retries: 5
  delay: 2
  when: hadoop_type_of_node == 'master'
```

However Ansible seems incapable of reading the line `sudo: False`. When I ran this playbook I still got this error:

```
TASK [ansible-role-hadoop : get_url] **************************************************************************************************
FAILED - RETRYING: ansible-role-hadoop : get_url (5 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: ansible-role-hadoop : get_url (4 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: ansible-role-hadoop : get_url (3 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: ansible-role-hadoop : get_url (2 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: ansible-role-hadoop : get_url (1 retries left).
fatal: [54.201.26.110 -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"attempts": 5, "changed": false, "module_stderr": "sudo: a password is required\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 1}
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/peng/git/datapassport/clusterops/ansible/deploy/master.retry
```

Why is this line not read and what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`become: false`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/become.html#become), not `sudo: false` which has been deprecated long ago.

`sudo` declaration is still kept for compatibility in plays definitions, but for some reason has been not maintained in tasks since Ansible 2.4.

---

<sup>- There is no check for declarations in tasks (you can add `foo: bar` to a task and it will be ignored). That's why you don't see any error/warning.</sup>

<sup>- On the other hand, you should get a warning about `sudo` being deprecated.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

[Privilege Escalation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/become.html#become) is important to manage in Ansible. The **become** keyword is the operator for this ability.

4 common uses:

- **become**
  set to ‘true’/’yes’ to activate privilege escalation.
- **become_user**
  set to user with desired privileges — the user you ‘become’, NOT the user you login as. Does NOT imply become: yes, to allow it to be set at host level.
- **become_method**
  (at play or task level) overrides the default method set in ansible.cfg, set to sudo/su/pbrun/pfexec/doas/dzdo/ksu
- **become_flags** (at play or task level) permit to use specific flags for the tasks or role. One common use is to change user to nobody when the shell is set to no login.

So, <s>sudo: yes</s>, use `become:` like this:

```
- hosts: master
  user: ec2-user
  become: false
```